# Estimate normal distribution parameters from smallest N samples

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, order-statistics

I have a bunch of small datasets (billions of sets of 7 samples). Each dataset represents the smallest 7 samples of a larger set of 15 values which are normally distributed. Given just the smallest 7 samples, how could I calculate the mean/stdev for the full 15 sample set efficiently?

I suspect this involves using order statistics and the beta distribution but this is going beyond my usual depth in stats.

Comment: Is the remark on billions of sets relevant for the question? Otherwise this is a standard order statistic case with a well-defined likelihood.

Comment: It's only relevant in respect to the efficiently. Solutions that involve complex operations such as integration or multiple passes over the data won't be viable. This data is astrological in nature and the universe is "big", so lots of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207403/estimating-a-normal-distribution-from-three-order-statistics

Comment: A simple, appealing method is "ROS"--regression on order statistics.  You plot the lower arm of the Normal probability plot, fit a line to it any way you please, and read the parameter estimates right off the intercept and slope of the line.  You can precompute the probability plotting points, so this can all be done with simple and fast algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Applying method-of-moments to a truncated normal is an attractive alternative to an MLE approach. It appears to give small improvements on predictions compared to the RoS approach outlined by @whuber at a small cost in performance (once both approaches are optimized). However, RoS is more readily generalized to other distributions.

For sets of 7 samples, a vectorized R implementation processes > 15M sets per second on my laptop.

---

Although we observe the smallest $k$ of $n$ values, we will treat the observations as iid from a truncated normal distribution. The first two [moments of a truncated normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#One_sided_truncation_(of_upper_tail)) are defined in terms of the underlying (untruncated) normal distribution, the standard normal distribution, and the truncation point, $\beta$.

If $\Phi^{-1}(\cdot)$ is the inverse CDF of the standard normal distribution, we'll treat the observed values as truncated at $\beta=\Phi^{-1}\Big(\frac{k+1}{n+1}\Big)$.

Implemented in R along with a vectorized version of @whuber's `ROS` function, both of which accept a matrix with $k$ columns:

```
library(Rfast)

fMoM <- function(x, n, d = 1) {
  # parameter estimates using method of moments on a truncated normal
  k <- ncol(x)
  beta <- qnorm((k + d)/(n + 1))
  r <- dnorm(beta)/pnorm(beta)
  mu <- rowmeans(x)
  s <- sqrt(rowsums((x - mu)^2)/(k - 1)/(1 - beta*r - r^2))
  data.frame(mu = mu + s*r, s = s)
}

fRoS <- function(x, n) {
  p <- qnorm(seq(1/n/2, (ncol(x) - 0.5)/n, 1/n))
  pp <- mean(p)
  ppp <- p - pp
  xx <- rowmeans(x)
  s <- mmult((x - xx), ppp)/sum(ppp^2)
  data.frame(mu = xx - s*pp, s = s)
}
```

`fRoS` uses `RcppArmadillo` matrix multiplication:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP mmult(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> A, Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> B){
  Eigen::MatrixXd C = A * B;
  return Rcpp::wrap(C);
}
```

Timing 100M sets of 7 observations:

```
N <- 1e8L
k <- 7L
n <- 15L

x <- rowSort(matrix(rnorm(n*N), N))[,1:k]

system.time({varMoM <- fMoM(x, n)})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    5.10    1.36    6.50
system.time({varRoS <- fRoS(x, n)})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    4.18    0.79    4.96
```

I'll attempt to compare accuracy by comparing the KL divergences from each method against the true underlying distribution:

```
KL_MoM <- with(varMoM, (s^2 + mu^2 - 1)/2 - log(s))
KL_RoS <- with(varRoS, (s^2 + mu^2 - 1)/2 - log(s))

mean(KL_MoM)
# [1] 0.1877256
mean(KL_RoS)
# [1] 0.1921236

hMoM <- hist(KL_MoM, 1000, plot = FALSE)
hRoS <- hist(KL_RoS, hMoM$breaks, plot = FALSE)
plot(hMoM, col = adjustcolor("blue", 0.25), xlim = c(0, 1.5))
plot(hRoS, col = adjustcolor("red", 0.25), xlim = c(0, 1.5), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

The distribution of `KL_MoM` is slightly more concentrated near 0 than is the distribution of `KL_RoS`.

---

**An MLE approach is still feasible with a large data set.** The most straightforward way to speed it up is to find a way to vectorize the optimization problem. Since the log-likelihood function is twice differentiable, Newton-Raphson is doable after some derivation work. It can also be vectorized. My attempt to implement it efficiently in R results in a function that can process 1M sets of $k=7$ in about 3 seconds.

```
fMLE <- function(x, n, params0, relax = 0.25, tol = 1e-8, maxIter = 20L) {
  # initialize constants
  k <- ncol(x)
  nk <- n - k
  const1 <- 1/sqrt(2*pi)
  sumx <- rowsums(x)
  sumx2 <- rowsums(x^2)
  xk2 <- x[,k]^2
  
  if (length(nrow(params0))) {
    mu <- params0[,1]
    s <- params0[,2]
  } else {
    mu <- params0[1]
    s <- params0[2]
  }
  
  muOut <- sOut <- numeric(nrow(x))
  idx <- 1:nrow(x)
  iter <- 0L
  
  # Newton-Raphson steps
  while(length(idx) & iter < maxIter) {
    mu0 <- mu
    s0 <- s
    d <- x[idx, k, drop = FALSE] - mu
    d2 <- d^2
    s2 <- s^2
    mu2 <- mu^2
    E <- exp(-d2/s2/2)*const1/pnorm(d/s, lower.tail = FALSE)
    E2 <- nk*s*E^2
    E <- E*nk
    A <- E*d - k*s - E2
    B <- 2*(k*mu - sumx[idx]) - (E2*d + E*(s2 - d2))/s
    D <- k*s + (3*(2*mu*sumx[idx] - sumx2[idx] - k*mu2))/s + (E*d*(mu2 - 2*s2 - 2*mu*x[idx, k, drop = FALSE] + xk2[idx]) - E2*d2)/s2
    DAB2 <- (A*D - B^2)/s/(1 - (1 - relax)^(iter <- iter + 1L)) # progressively relax the relaxation
    G <- E*s + sumx[idx] - k*mu
    H <- E*d + (k*(mu2 - s2) - 2*mu*sumx[idx] + sumx2[idx])/s
    mu <- mu - (D*G - B*H)/DAB2
    s <- s - (A*H - B*G)/DAB2
    blnKeep <- abs((mu - mu0)/mu) > tol & abs((s- s0)/s) > tol
    muOut[idx[!blnKeep]] <- mu[!blnKeep]
    sOut[idx[!blnKeep]] <- s[!blnKeep]
    mu <- mu[blnKeep]
    s <- s[blnKeep]
    idx <- idx[blnKeep]
  }
  
  data.frame(mu = muOut, s = sOut)
}
```

We'll use a smaller dataset and the MoM approach to get the initial values:

```
N <- 1e7L
x <- rowSort(matrix(rnorm(n*N), N))[,1:k]

system.time({varMoM <- fMoM(x, n)})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.42    0.05    0.47
system.time({varRoS <- fRoS(x, n)})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.32    0.06    0.39
system.time({varMLE <- fMLE(x, n, varMoM)})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   26.61    4.47   31.11
```

Again, comparing the results with KL divergence:

```
KL_MLE <- with(varMLE, (s^2 + mu^2 - 1)/2 - log(s))
KL_MoM <- with(varMoM, (s^2 + mu^2 - 1)/2 - log(s))
KL_RoS <- with(varRoS, (s^2 + mu^2 - 1)/2 - log(s))

mean(KL_MLE)
#> [1] 0.1732725
mean(KL_MoM)
#> [1] 0.1877734
mean(KL_RoS)
#> [1] 0.1921714
```

Or comparing their log-likelihoods:

```
fLL <- function(x, vars, n) {
  (n - ncol(x))*pnorm(x[,ncol(x)], vars[,1], vars[,2], FALSE, TRUE) - 
    rowSums((x - vars[,1])^2)/2/vars[,2]^2 - ncol(x)*log(vars[,2])
}

LL_MLE <- fLL(x, varMLE, n)
LL_MoM <- fLL(x, varMoM, n)
LL_RoS <- fLL(x, varRoS, n)

mean(LL_MLE)
#> [1] -7.353136
mean(LL_MoM)
#> [1] -7.493138
mean(LL_RoS)
#> [1] -7.515774
```

Comment: +1 As far as timing goes, the optimizations I indicated for `RoS` in my post triple its performance, which would bring your time down from 15.7 to less than 6 seconds.  The accuracy results for MoM are encouraging, but we should be more interested in the distribution of the estimates than in any single measure of accuracy.

Comment: I believe I applied those optimizations. Note that `fRoS` is vectorized, so the `pp` vector is computed once, and `cov` is vectorized over the full `x` matrix. One thing that may be slowing it down is the transpose. If `x` were fed as a wide matrix, the transpose could be avoided. The scatterplots look very similar to the ones you produced for the RoS. I'll plan on adding them when I have time.

Comment: Those aren't much in the way of optimizations.  By preprocessing `pp` appropriately you can obtain the array of all values of a given estimated parameter through a single matrix multiplication.  That's far faster than what I see in `fRoS`.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do almost as well as Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) using Regression on Order Statistics (RoS).**  The latter is simpler to program (requiring only sorting and straightforward arithmetic) and it's thirty times faster in execution (when optimized as described below).

---

The idea of RoS is to fit a line--using any method you like--to the observed data on a censored probability plot.  In this image of 15 points only the lowest 7 (black) points were used to fit that line.  The plotting points are quantiles of the standard Normal distribution and (therefore) the line's intercept estimates the median (which equals the mean) and its slope estimates the standard deviation.

[image]

You can precompute the plotting points because they depend only on the common size of the datasets, $15.$  A least-squares calculation of the line's parameters is ultimately a dot product: see the code for `ROS` below.  You can speed it up by precomputing the variance of the plotting points and simplifying the algebra.  It is massively parallelizable.

**How well does this perform?**  Here are the results of applying ROS along with censored Maximum Likelihood (requiring numerical optimization) for 5,000 randomly generated Normal datasets.

[image]

The plots are similar.  Both show the estimates tend to be near the true values (plotted as the red points) and, as one would expect, positively correlated.  But the MLE results are a little bit more precise.  Here is a comparison of the standard deviations in this simulation:

```
    Intercept Slope
RoS     0.366 0.333
MLE     0.336 0.286
```

That is, RoS with 7 points is about as good as MLE with 6 points.

In any given instance, RoS and MLE tend to agree, as these scatterplots of their estimates in the simulation attest.

[image]

The bottom line is

> If greater efficiency is worth the amount of information in one data point (or more), then RoS is a good choice.

Here are my `R` implementations of these methods and the simulation.

```R
#
# `x` is the bottom `k` order statistics and `pp` are their corresponding
# Normal plotting points.  Returns an (intercept, slope) vector of estimates.
#
ROS <- function(x, pp) {
  s <- cov(x, pp) / var(pp)
  m <- mean(x - s * pp)
  c(Intercept = m, Slope = s)
}
#
# `x` is the bottom `k` data points and `n` is the total size of the dataset 
# they are from.   Returns an (intercept, slope) vector of estimates.
#
MLE <- function(x, n) {
  y <- sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
  k <- length(x)
  lambda <- function(theta) { # Negative log likelihood
    mu <- theta[1]
    sigma <- exp(theta[2])
    -sum(dnorm(y, mu, sigma, log = TRUE)) - 
      (n - k) * pnorm(y[1], mu, sigma, log = TRUE, lower.tail = FALSE)
  }
  beta <- optim(c(0, 0), lambda)$par
  c(Intercept = beta[1], Slope = exp(beta[2]))
}
#
# Apply both methods to simulated datasets.
#
set.seed(17)
k <- 7
n <- 15
pp <- qnorm(seq(0, 1, length.out = 2*n+1)[2 * seq_len(n)])
sim <- replicate(5e3, {
  x <- sort(rnorm(n))        # A random sample
  y <- x[seq_len(k)]         # Its `k` lowest elements
  b <- ROS(y, pp[seq_len(k)])
  b.MLE <- MLE(y, n)
  c(b, b.MLE)                # The four estimates (in each column).
})
#
# Print the standard deviations of the four estimates.
#
(matrix(signif(apply(sim, 1, sd), 3), 2, 
 dimnames = list(c("RoS", "MLE"), c("Intercept", "Slope"))))
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1).  Since RoS relies on the theoretical quantiles of the normal distribution, it looks like it would be much less robust to misspecification of the distributional family than the MLE.  It might be worth specifying that as a caveat to your initial sentence.

Comment: @Ben That's an interesting point.  I recall (deep in the mists of time, 30 years ago when I studied the properties of RoS) that RoS is more robust to the specification than you might think.  You could employ this code to perform a simulation study if you like: modifying `ROS` is easy.

Answer (score 1):

The joint density is given at [Joint density of first r order statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109472/joint-density-of-first-r-order-statistics), and then just use maximum likelihood. Leaving out the combinatorial factor (which is irrelevant to the maximization), the log likelihood is (with $f$ denoting the normal density function, $F$ the corresponding cdf)
$$ \ell(\mu,\sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^7 \log f(x_i) + (15-7)\log\left(1-F(x_7)\right) $$
and then just use numerical optimization.

For more details see the answer at the similar question https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/276322/11887

Comment: Based on the link that you provided, will there not be other components like $F\left(x_2\right) - F\left(x_1\right), F\left(x_3\right) - F\left(x_2\right)..$?